# Google Places Autocomplete Angular Pattern Validation For USA Address

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, validation, google-places-autocomplete

For some reason I can't figure out a proper regular expression to handle validating addresses selected from the Google Places Autocomplete plugin. I want addresses to pass validation with the following constraints:

- must be preceded by number
- unit/apt numbers are optional
- must end with "USA"

Examples of valid addresses:
284 5th Ave, Chicago, IL, USA
284 Fifth Ave, Chicago, IL, USA
284 Fifth Ave Unit 203, Chicago, IL, USA
284 Fifth Ave Apt 203, Chicago, IL, USA

I can get a valid response with the following regex, but it doesn't require "USA" at the end:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+[A-z0-9 ,]$/i)
```

As soon as I add USA in it stops validating:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+[A-z0-9 ,]+(usa)$/i)
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+[A-z0-9 ,]+usa$/i)
```

Validation is implemented as so:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" *ngIf="AddressForm.controls['location'].hasError('pattern') && AddressForm.controls['location'].touched">Please select a valid address.</span>
```

I realize this is a very basic regex, so any suggestions to improve it will be greatly appareciated.

Comment: Maybe a simple [`/^[0-9].*\bUSA$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/lzr9D0/2) will do? Starts with a digit and ends with `USA` as a whole word, and in between, there can be anything?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - still giving me an invalid response. As far as anything being allowed in there, I was just trying to simplify it because of my lacking in ability to write regexes. Ideally I wanted it to validate it to be a string that starts with numbers followed by a space then alphanumeric characters (street), a comma, as many letters as they want for the city, another comma, 2 letters for the state, a comma, and then USA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I was trying something like this before I made it much simpler:
**^[0-9]+[A-z0-9 ]+,+[A-z ]+,+\s+[A-Z]{2},\sUSA**

Comment: First of all, do not use `[A-z]` as [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: At any rate, I see `^[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9 ,]+(usa)$` works, what is the problem you are having? Please consider sharing a JS fiddle to repro the issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - looks like it has something to do with how the address is being returned by the api. When I type in an address manually it passes validation, however, when I pick an address using Google Places Autocomplete, it doesn't.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-lake-ylqdu?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Looks like the value on the input is pulling in whatever was typed vs what was selected from the dropdown. That being said, I'm going to use the address change event to set a hidden input and just have the validation message target that input.

Comment: Yeah, the regex itself is fine, the problem is within he code.